# How to make two different range slider inputs show the same value, whenever the user updates one of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, range

So when ever the user changes the value of the range slider I want that both range sliders get updated to the same value. The same value will then be printed on the P > span. The second part is working but I can't get them to show the same value. (I want the range slider handel to be exact the same for both of them.) **Extra:** Is there anyway to convert this to jQuery and remove the JS part from the HTML? Thanks for your time.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <label for="maximumReadTime">Maximale Leestijd</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="30" step="15" id="maximumReadTimeMobile" onchange="updateUserMaximumReadTime(this.value);">
    <p class="userMaximumReadTimeFeedback"><span id="userMaximumReadTimeMobile">30</span> min</p>
</form>

<form>
    <label for="maximumReadTime">Maximale Leestijd</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="30" step="15" id="maximumReadTime" onchange="updateUserMaximumReadTime(this.value);">
    <p class="userMaximumReadTimeFeedback"><span id="userMaximumReadTime">30</span> min</p>
</form>
```

**JS:** I have tested .value on the range input but it did not work.

```
function updateUserMaximumReadTime(val) {
  document.getElementById('userMaximumReadTime').innerHTML = val;
  document.getElementById('userMaximumReadTimeMobile').innerHTML = val;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example that should help get you in the right direction.

```
$('input[type=range]').on('change', function() {
  $('input[type=range]').val($(this).val())
});
```

```js
$('input[type=range]').on('change', function() {
  $('input[type=range]').val($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <label for="maximumReadTime">Maximale Leestijd</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="30" step="15" id="maximumReadTimeMobile">
    <p class="userMaximumReadTimeFeedback"><span id="userMaximumReadTimeMobile">30</span> min</p>
</form>

<form>
    <label for="maximumReadTime">Maximale Leestijd</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="60" value="30" step="15" id="maximumReadTime">
    <p class="userMaximumReadTimeFeedback"><span id="userMaximumReadTime">30</span> min</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make one class for both ranges. Then on update You need to call c allback function that will apply this value to other range elements.

```
$('.rangeSlider').range({
    update : function (currentSlider){
        $('.rangeSlider').range({ value : currentSlider.value });
    }
 });
```

It's example of 'how it can be done'.
When i will back home - i'm will be available to give You much wider explanation.

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but WHAT? I understand the class part but the function part is kinda hard for me.

Comment: Did You ever used jQuery?

Comment: @Roman, please elaborate. Your answer is not useful in its current form. It's as broad as saying "write some code to do this."

Comment: @Robusto, clever one? Try to do it on mobile :)

Comment: @RomanKozin yes, but only for basic stuff like toggles for mobile menu's. jQuery is loaded anyway so I prefer to keep the entire file jQuerry only.